# Querying a server and displaying returned JSON into a ListView

Tags: android

I would like to query my PHP server and display the result in a `ListView` in Android. The problem is, I keep on getting this error: `JSONArray cannot be coverted to JSONObject`. Please be patient with me, because I tried most of the solutions to the similar error but cannot seem to get it working.

http://congomikili.com/android_login_api/retrieve_polls_names.php gives me the following data on my browser:

```
[{"0":"who will win the next election","name":"who will win the next election"},{"0":"who ","name":"who "}]
```

After running my application, however, I am getting a blank screen.

Comment: How can we possibly help without seeing your code and error log output?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that your problem is that you're treating the reply as a JSONObject when what you have to do is to parse it as a JSONArray,and then loop in the array to get the JSONObjects,in this case, there are two of them.Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use JSONArray first and get the index of each JSONObject